# View Controllers - Suggestions from documentation

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

> Note: If you want to divide a view hierarchy into multiple subareas
>   and manage each one     separately, use generic controller objects
>   (custom objects descending from NSObject) instead     of view
>   controller objects to manage each subarea. Then use a single view
>   controller object to     manage the generic controller objects.

The above quote is from the iOS Programming Guide.  My questions are :

1
About the bracketed term "(custom objects descending from NSObject)", does it refer to a general object subclassed from NSObject or an object created by subclassing from the UIViewController class ?

2
From the last sentence, about the "single view controller" , does it refer to a root view controller or does it refer to any content controllers that one might use for the nodes of his view hierarchy ?

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with you that could get some clarification, you should give them a feedback about that.

Now for my interpretation.
1.  Yes NSObject subclass
2.  I think they mean different subareas of your screen. Which would means don't create multiple UIViewController subclass to control deferent part of your screen, create custom controller managed by a single UIViewController.

Comment: 2. unless you are using the new iOS 5 API's for doing so

Comment: @Paul.s That documentation was made pre-iOS5. I haven't check iOS 5, what's the API? I'm really curios about it. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Paul.s, so do I, please tell me more about the difference in iOS5.

Comment: Check out `Implementing a Container View Controller` in the current docs http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: If your signed up to the developer program there is also a talk about it which discusses when and when not to use view containment. The session is `Session 102 - Implementing UIViewController Containment`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Paul.c + VinceBurn.

Comment: @Paul.s Thanks, to say that I've look at that documentation in the last 3 weeks and I've mist that little section.

Comment: @VinceBurn, guess I have misinterpreted the word "subareas". The view hierarchy the document is referring to is the view hierarchy within a single window (not about multiple screens).  So your interpretation should be the right one.  Thanks!

Comment: @Stanley, yes about the documentation, but Paul.s is pointing out something that every iPad developer will want to know about while porting an iPhone app to the iPad.